# Energy expenditure due to rotation of a dumbbell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy

I have recently taken an interest in energy conversions and how it is connected to motion in classical mechanics. Sadly, I'm not really up to speed when it comes to the mathematics and derivations of the various energy formulas such as kinetic energy, rotational energy, moments of inertia, etc. With this question, I'd like to see if my intuition is in the right place before moving on to the derivations.

Consider the following two designs of a dumbbell that can be used in the gym:

1. The weights are fully fixed onto the handlebar

The weights cannot slide along the length of the handlebar as if they were glued or screwed on and you cannot rotate the weights without also rotating the handlebar. Behaves as if it were a solid object with different local densities.

2. The weights are held in place but can rotate frictionlessly

The weights are held in place as to prevent them from sliding along the length of the handlebar, but they can rotate along the handlebar frictionlessly like a loose washer around a screw.

The dimensions and properties of the weights and the handlebar are otherwise identical. Both the weights and the handlebar have uniform densities.

### Testing my intuition

I'm assuming that lifting a dumbbell of the first design will require more effort than one that's built on the second design; not only are you lifting the same total mass and rotating the handlebar in both scenarios, you are putting in an extra effort to rotate the weighted discs around their central axis in the first scenario.

### Calculating the difference in energy usage

If we assume the handlebar to be a slim cylinder with some radius $r_{handle}$, height $h_{handle}$ and mass $m_{handle}$, and we have two identical cylinders with holes in them with an outer radius $r_{weight}$, an inner radius equal to the handlebar's, a thickness of $h_{weight}$ and a mass $m_{weight}$, is it actually possible to calculate the difference in energy usage when lifting either dumbbells?

I'm imagining the athlete to have their upper arm hanging perpendicularly to the ground. If $\theta$ represents the angle between the upper arm and the forearm (length $L_{forearm}$) of someone doing a bicep curl at some constant angular velocity $\omega_{arm}$.

What elements would I need to calculate the total expended energy for both design, say for $\theta_0 = 2\pi$ and $\theta_1 = \frac{\pi}{6}$?

Would this be different if the athlete instead lifted the weight with an angular acceleration $\alpha_{arm}$ and an initial angular velocity of $\omega_{arm} = 0$?